# How should I go about encrypting users' IDs with JWT when I NEED the users' ID for front-end applications

Tags: express, vuejs3, express-jwt

I’m making a little social media project and I am getting into encryption of data.
Stack: Vue3, MongoDB, and Express

I’m working with JWT to encrypt the user’s ID so that if anyone (who’s not the user) gets ahold of their UserID, they can’t POST, GET, or PUT any information that they shouldn’t have access to just by using the UserID in the request body.

**The Issue:**

I want to encrypt the current user’s ID so no one else can use it without the JW token

The user has attributes including people they follow, posts they’ve made, etc..

I need to use the user’s ID, however, in the front end, so that posts (that belong to the user) are allowed to be edited (and it’ll only show the pencil icon if the user owns that post)

I’m a little lost because I want to hide the user’s ID, but I NEED that ID for front end experience